# Check plagiarism in a word archive

Tags: application

I have done a lot of homework.I get some help  (gather informations) from  articles,etc using the Internet.What I want is to avoid plagiarism.I get in some sites but it is English to English.I want English to my country language which is Greeks. I search but I failed.First , I want to help me (of course if you could)  with it to find a specific program.If not, I want to avoid plagiarism or another aspect how to handle this.

Comment: Do you mean a tool that first translates and then checks for matching texts? This will be hard, since not even back-translating a translated text on google will give you the original text (i.e. A -> B -> A' won't result in A=A')

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write down notes during your research, make sure you clearly indicate two things:

1. The source you are taking notes from  (at this stage this can be as simple as pasting a link).
2. Whether a statement is a direct quote, or your words.

As long as you do this, and then use those notes appropriately, you won't have to worry about accidentally plagiarising when you draw on these notes to write a paper.

And it's really the only solution. Whether a tool exists for Greek, I don't know. But even the tools that exist for English are imperfect. They are designed to catch cheaters (as much as possible). But passing one of these tools doesn't prove that you have not plagiarized.

Comment: Neither does *not* passing a tool prove that you *have* plagiarized.